# would you mock the class under test as well like "inherit and override"?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

When I use mockito framework I usually mock only collaborators of the class under test (CUT).

However I saw in "Working effectively with legacy code" a way to write UT sometimes.

Where there is too much logic in one method.

you would:

1) extract some logic code to a separate method

2) inherit the CUT and override this method

3) mock this method if we don't want to run this code (it's less relevant to our test)

Then I have thought that I never mocked methods in my CUT, only collaborators.

Would you ever mock methods of CUT?

How would you mock methods of CUT and collaborators of CUT at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is indeed sometimes a useful thing to do. Mockito has spies, allowing to mock some methods of an existing object. For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public int bar() {
        return baz() * 2;
    }
    protected int baz() {
        // some computation you want to mock
    }
}
```

You could write a test of bar() this way:

```
// given
Foo foo = new Foo();
Foo spy = spy(foo);
doReturn(5).when(spy).baz();

// when
int result = spy.bar();

// then
assertEquals(10, result);
```

Mockito also has partial mocks. Everything is described in the [Mockito javadoc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html).

Doing the above and also mocking collaborators simply consists in passing mocked collaborators to the object under test:

```
Collaborator mockCollaborator = mock(Collaborator.class);
Foo foo = new Foo(mockCollaborator);
Foo spy = spy(foo);
...
```